# How to handle timeout exception in quarkus?

Tags: exception, quarkus, fault, timeoutexception, microprofile

I am trying to connect to a third-party API from quarkus controller . I have a controller using the method of service. The try catch block is not working.I have all the required dependency and i followed quarkus doc
Here is the code

Controller

```
package com.ncr.invoice;

// all imports over here 

@Path("/api")
@RequestScoped
public class InvoiceController {
    // all variable and injection 
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/invoice")
    @Timeout(250)
    @PermitAll
    public Response getInvoice(AuthTokenRequestModel atrm){
            SoupResponseInvoiceDetail srid = null;
            try{
                 srid = service.getInvoice(
                    atrm.getMcn(),"transactionId", atrm.getInvoiceNumber()
                 );
                 LOG.info("try block end");
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                LOG.info("Over here");
                return Response.status(401).build();
            }
          
            return Response.ok(srid).build();
        }

        return Response.status(401).build();
    }

 
    // all getter setter 
}
```

service

```
package com.ncr.invoice;

//all imports 

@Path("/")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="invoice-api")
@ClientHeaderParam(name = "Authorization", value = "{basicAuth}")
public interface InvoiceService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/")
    public SoupResponseInvoiceDetail getInvoice(@QueryParam("id") String id,@QueryParam("txn_id") String txnId, @QueryParam("invoice") String invoice) throws InterruptedException;

    default String basicAuth() {
        String uName = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("auth.username", String.class);
        String pwd = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("auth.pwd", String.class);
        String creds =  uName + ":" + pwd;
        return "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(creds.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Error that i am getting

```
2021-01-07 13:07:42,286 INFO  [com.ncr.inv.InvoiceController] (executor-thread-189) try block end
2021-01-07 13:07:42,555 ERROR [io.und.req.io] (executor-thread-189) Exception handling request 58a6d4b3-76c1-4a8b-b4a0-1e241219fb4d-4 to /api/invoice: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.eclipse.microprofile.faulttolerance.exceptions.TimeoutException: Timeout[com.ncr.invoice.InvoiceController#getInvoice] timed out
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
.........................................
```

Comment: Looks like you want to make sure that the external service invocation doesn't take too long? In which case, just move `@Timeout(250)` from the endpoint (`InvoiceController.getInvoice`) to the client interface (`InvoiceService.getInvoice`). And in the endpoint, catch the `TimeoutException`.

Answer (score 1):

To me it look like you need to need to do something like this:

```
@Provider
public class TimeoutExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<TimeoutException> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());    
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(TimeoutException exception) {
        LOGGER.warn(exception.getMessage());
        return getResponse();
    }

    public static Response getResponse() {      
        ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();
        response.setDescription("Operation timet out, try again later");
        return status(Response.Status.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT).entity(response).build();
    }
}
```